# Add change event to every table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to detect changes in an html table consisting of normal text cells as well as all kinds of different input cells.  From previous questions the best that I could find was the following:

```
$("td").change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Simple enough right?  Adds a change event to every table cell.  However the problem is it only works on cells containing input.  Any idea how to make them work on normal text cells such as:

```
<td>Hello World</td>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What sort of `change`s would occur to a non-input field? Is it `contenteditable` or something?

Comment: Change only works on input fileds

Comment: Normal text is entered in non-input fields.  What I obviously can do is make all other text cells inputs as well?

Comment: use `contenteditable="true"` Attribute

Comment: What type of element are you talking about (besides input cells)? Checkboxes? Listboxes? Textareas?

Comment: I am doing that...

Comment: SELECT | 
Input Text | 
Input Checkbox |

Comment: @5740382, if you make a **NON-INPUT** element as `contenteditable`, any change you do to it would have no effect at all, so what would be the point in doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set contenteditable attribute to true `contenteditable="true"` and `input` event

```js
$("td").on('input',function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">January</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did use contentEditable.  What made the difference was your JS on('input').  Thanks for the help!